# how to use React-Hook-Form on Antd Input?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, react-hook-form, react-forms

How can I use react-hook-form on antd inputs ?

usually its like this

```js
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

// Render
            <Input
              {...register("firstName")}
              className="my-2"
              placeholder="First Name *"
            />
```

it works ok with MUI Text Field but not with Antd Input.

i only get empty string;

I Would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 1):

You can use Controller from 'react-hook-form' to wrap antd input.

[Docs exampe](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries)

[In your case it can be like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-zi6h95?file=/index.js:226-884):

```
const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "1",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      password: ""
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>antd version: {version}</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Item label="first name">
          <Controller
            name="firstName"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Input {...field} className="my-2" placeholder="First Name *" />
            )}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```